# Lego Star Wars The Force Awakens free character mode in hubs?

Tags: lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

I can't figure out how to unlock character switching on the hubs. I know for the levels you have to go back and do free play but when I am in the hubs I can't switch between characters!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to play through the whole story in order to unlock free play in the hubs.

Depending on the platform you are playing on, there are different ways to get to the character grid. For Xbox One, press and hold Y, PS4 press and hold Triangle, and (*i'm sorry, I don't know what the button is on PC :(* ) the character wheel will come up. From there you can access the character grid to select the whole cast.

Answer (score 1):

In order to unlock free play (character-switching) in the hub areas, you need to complete all of the main story missions in the game.